# transitive verb "distract"

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitivity, intransitive-preposition

I learned and know that the transitive verb must go with *object*, and some verbs contain both transitive and intransitive but others only have transitive and intransitive, respectively.

and the verb **distract** is a transitive verb which does not involve intransitive verb.

and I found one sentence from my textbook,

-> When a room is well organized, there is nothing to **distract** from the work.

here, even though the verb **distract** is a transitive verb, it goes with *preposition* **from**, which generally follows after the intransitive verb.

How this sentence can be grammatical?

Comment: "Distract" is normally a transitive verb, but in your example the direct object is unexpressed but recoverable from the context. Intransitive "distract" is interpreted as "distract one/you".

Answer (score 2):

You are right, "distract" is a transitive verb, which means that we use a direct object after it.

However, the object is omitted in the sentence *"When a room is well organized, there is nothing to distract (the direct object should be here) from the work".*

But it's possible to **distract** somebody **from** something: *Don't distract her from her studies. He distracted our attention from the issue.* As you can see, "from" is used after the object and it doesn't make the verb intransitive.

Personally, I'd say *"When a room is well organized, there is nothing to distract you from the work".*

Answer (score 1):

From [illinois.edu](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/prepphrases/): "There are two kinds of prepositional phrases: adjective phrases and adverb phrases." In this case, "from the work" is an adverb phrase modifying "distract".

Examples:

> He distracted the man.
>   He distracted the man from the work.

Also, in your sentence, there seems to be an implied "you".

> there is nothing to distract (you) from the work.
>   there is nothing to distract (one) from the work.

Comment: wow thank you a lot! Your answer really enlighten me!

Comment: It is preferable to analyse "from his work" as a complement of "distract", rather than a modifier. Note that "from his work" is a PP, not an AdvP. You're conflating category and function, a common mistake among learners.

Comment: @BillJ Then "from his work" outwardly seems PP but it function as AdvP?

Comment: @Belle no: AdvP is a phrase type (like AdjP, NP etc.) not a function. "From the work" belongs to the category PP, and its function is that of complement.